# JavaScript count variables from an array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following JavaScript syntax:

```
console.log(printClassified(classifyByDayOfWeek(myData)));
mySundaysData = new Array(printClassified(classifyByDayOfWeek(myData)));
console.log(mySundaysData);
var mySundaysTotal = 0;
for(var i=0, len=mySundaysData.length; i<len; i++){
    mySundaysTotal += parseFloat(mySundaysData[i][1]);
}
console.log(mySundaysTotal);
```

Google Chrome console:

```
printClassified(classifyByDayOfWeek(myData)) = [2013-04-21, 1][2013-04-28, 0][2013-05-05, 2][2013-05-12, 0]
mySundaysData = ["[2013-04-21, 1][2013-04-28, 0][2013-05-05, 2][2013-05-12, 0]"]
mySundaysTotal = 2
```

I want to count the values from the arrays, for the above example: 1 + 0 + 2 + 0 and it should give me 3 and instead it gives me 2 like it can be saw in the `console.log(mySundaysTotal)`. Even if I got other arrays mySundaysTotal is always 2. Why? What am I do wrong?

EDIT:
Rest of the code:

```
function sorter(a, b) {
    var d1 = new Date(a[0].replace("-", "/")).getDay();
    var d2 = new Date(b[0].replace("-", "/")).getDay();
    return d1 - d2;
}
function classifyByDayOfWeek(customArr) {
    var byDayOfWeek = [[], [], [], [], [], [], []];
    for (var i = 0; i < customArr.length; i++) {
        var day = new Date(customArr[i][0]).getDay();
        byDayOfWeek[day].push(customArr[i]);
    };
    return byDayOfWeek;
}
function printRaw(arr) {
    str = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        str += "[" + arr[i][0] + ", " + arr[i][1] + "]";
    }
    return str;
}
function printClassified(arr) {
    str = "";
    str += printRaw(arr[0]);
    return str;
}
```

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/DanielaVaduva/NUHFu/

Comment: @PSR - in the initialisation part of the for loop, len is set to the length of the array (which, in this case is 1)

Comment: @alex23 I've tried it to see if it makes a difference or not...

Comment: Why you don't create this exercise on http://jsfiddle.net/  ?

Comment: @MirkoCianfarani I will do it right now :D. EDIT - http://jsfiddle.net/DanielaVaduva/NUHFu/

Comment: I need the value of variable myDAta...

Comment: I find the variable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I have are refined answer. The parsing could do with some work, but:

```
var raw = "\"['2013-04-15', 26]\", \"['2013-04-16', 10]\", \"['2013-04-17', 51]\", \"['2013-04-18', 46]\", \"['2013-04-19', 32]\", \"['2013-04-20', 50]\", \"['2013-04-21', 26]\", \"['2013-04-22', 31]\", \"['2013-04-23', 48]\", \"['2013-04-24', 821]\", \"['2013-04-25', 917]\", \"['2013-04-26', 949]\", \"['2013-04-27', 405]\", \"['2013-04-28', 593]\", \"['2013-04-29', 925]\", \"['2013-04-30', 877]\", \"['2013-05-01', 277]\", \"['2013-05-02', 112]\", \"['2013-05-03', 115]\", \"['2013-05-04', 62]\", \"['2013-05-05', 74]\", \"['2013-05-06', 76]\", \"['2013-05-07', 51]\", \"['2013-05-08', 93]\", \"['2013-05-09', 231]\", \"['2013-05-10', 350]\", \"['2013-05-11', 258]\", \"['2013-05-12', 0]\", \"['2013-05-13', 61]\"";

var json = raw.replace(/"/g,'');
json = "[" + json + "]";
json = json.replace(/'/g,'"');
myData = [];
var parsed = JSON.parse(json);
for(var i = 0, len=parsed.length; i < len; ++i ) {

    var date = new Date(parsed[i][0]); 
    myData.push( {
        date: date,
        day: date.getDay(),
        count: parsed[i][1]
    });
}

var mySundaysTotal = myData.
    filter(function(x) { return x.day == 0; }). //find sundays
    map(function(x) { return x.count; }). //get an array of the counts
    reduce(function(x,y) { return x+y; }, 0);  //sum the results

console.log(mySundaysTotal);
```

see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/tztLe/1/

Comment: And how can I get an array of arrays from that?